# "New Mirrored Volume" is disabled for fixed size VHD disks

Tags: windows, mirroring

I am doing a Windows Mirroring POC. I am using **windows 10 Enterprise** as my POC environment.

I created two fixed size VHD disks.

"New Mirrored Volume" is disabled per below screenshot:

[image]

Why are all the RAID options disabled?

**Update 1:**
Convert to Dynamic Disk is disabled too

[image]

**Update 2:**

It seems to be quite possible with Windows 7 Ultimate per blow post:
https://superuser.com/questions/116983/can-i-setup-a-software-raid-in-windows-7-using-virtual-hard-disks

Has anything changed with Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the disks from Basic to Dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for help. Please see my update. Convert to dynamic disk is disabled too.

Comment: Looking closer at your screenshot and re-reading your question, it looks like those are attached VHD files, right? I missed that in your question when I read it. I don't think you can convert attached VHD files from basic disks to dynamic disks.

Comment: please see my update 2. This is doable in Windows 7 ultimate. Do we know if it became more limited with windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you got to solve it, Allan Xu.  My experience: in Windows 10 you have to use Storage Pools.  This can be launched from the Control Panel